# Remove a delete action for database.yml file in GIT

Tags: git, version-control

When I pull from **origin master** in GIT, it has a delete action for **database.yml** file from a long-ago days.

Although the file is in **gitignore**, `pull origin master` does pull and kills the **database.yml**

Everytime. So mad. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete action"? Git hook? How is database.yml "killed"? Also removed unnecessary tags.

Comment: If a file is once committed then you cannot just simply add it to gitignore to hide it.

Comment: @bezet when you clone a repo, delete a file there and type `git status` it says: file deleted. Then you commit this deletion to a brach and merge it with master.

Comment: @AntonSemenichenko Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT hmmm... not yet

Comment: @AntonSemenichenko I add an answer to use `git filter-branch` to delete `database.yml` file thoroughly in the git repo. You can have a try.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`git filter-branch`** to delete the `database.yml` file thoroughly. Detail steps as below:

```
git pull origin master
#If database.yml also existing on another branches, please also pull other branches from origin
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached database.yml' --prune-empty -f -- --all
git push -f --all
```

**Note:** For the `git filter-branch` command, it will take a littler longer time since it delete the file from all the commit histories. And if `database.yml` file is not in the root of the git repo, you should add the relative path in this command.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to remove file from repository, keeping local copy, you can use:

```
git rm --cached file
```

This will stage file for deletion, but leave it intact locally. As noted in OP question, this "delete action" will happen in other clones of repository when merge(pull) will include commit that deletes the file.

To restore file in such case one can use:

```
git checkout <commit_id> -- file
```

As this will restore and instantly stage file, it is necessary to run `git rm --cached file` to remove it from index, keeping local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the file was checked in at some point, then the `.gitignore` was edited later.

Adding the file to `.gitignore` will prevent that file from making it into your repo if the file doesn't already exist there. Since the file already exists in the repo, adding it to `.gitignore` has no effect and your local copy's changes will be overwritten when switching branches.

To remove this file from your repo, make a backup of the file somewhere, delete the local file, check in the "change" (the file deletion) then push the change to the server. This will remove the file from your repo. Then restore your local copy.

Note that if you switch to a branch that doesn't have your new commit, then the file will still be replaced with the old version. It may take a while for the commit to make it's way into all of the other issue branches, so you might want to encourage colleagues to merge their issue branches with the master branch as soon as possible.

Comment: Adding file to `.gitignore` after it was added to repo will not prevent changes to it from being tracked.

Comment: @bezet - Hah! You are correct! Interesting. Will update.